# mysqli_query execution throws a http error 500

Tags: php, mysql, linux, forms, mysqli

Here's My setup I have gone over it twice already and have come up with nothing. 
I am currently working on a LAMP stack and most of the configurations have been done properly.
I have two files 
1. connect.php
2. registration.php

1. code of connect.php is as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$hostname="localhost"; //local server name
$username="user_name";  //mysql username
$password="my_password"; //mysql password
$database="my_database";  //database name 

// Create Connection to DB using an Object
$con= mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password); //do i need to pass database name also as an argument to this?

//Check Connection 
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo"Failed to connect! due to : " . mysqli_connect_errno();
} else{
    echo"Connected!";
}
?>
```

2. code of registration.php is as  follows:

```
<?php     //start php tag
include("/var/www/calculator/connect.php"); //using absolute path to avoid any confusion
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Connected! on Registration Page"); //executes till here with no problems
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE table users"))
{
    printf("Query Executed!", mysqli_affected_rows($conn))
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Some have suggested to take a look at the apache server logs here is the last 10 output of the logs

```
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:41 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:43 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:44 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:45 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:45 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:45 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:45 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:14:45 +0530] "GET /registration.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:15:37 +0530] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
::1 - - [24/Feb/2020:13:15:37 +0530] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"
```

I need help on why my queries are not getting executed despite my code having no coding errors or query structure errors.

Comment: That looks like your apache access logs, whats in your apache error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed `;`:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE table users"))
{
    printf("Query Executed!", mysqli_affected_rows($conn))    // <---- here
}
```

Also, read about [mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). You should use 4 arguments, but can pass `''` value in one of it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my silly mistake. Should I delete this to clear clutter?

Comment: No problem. It's up to you, you can do what you want.